# Filter by year and column number in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, subset

I am relatively new to R and I am trying to filter a data frame by year and specific column numbers. Here's a toy example of my data set:

```
Year    UniqueID       Bench.St   SiteEUI
2011      1              Yes        450
2011      2               No        300
2011      3               No         NA
2011      4               NA        350
2012      1               No        400
2012      2              Yes        200
2013      1              Yes        500
2013      2               No        100
2013      3              Yes        475
```

I am trying to extract the rows which have repeated information from 2011 to 2013 sorted through the UniqueIDs. Using the example above, 2011 has 4 UniqueIDs (1,2,3,4), 2012 has 2 UniqueIDs(1,2) and 2013 has 3 UniqueIDs(1,2,3). Since UniqueIDs 1 and 2 are present in the three years, I would like to extract the UniqueID rows for those years. Therefore the dataset above reduces to:

```
Year    UniqueID        Bench.St        SiteEUI
2011      1               Yes              450
2011      2                No              300
2012      1                No              400
2012      2               Yes              200
2013      1               Yes              500
2013      2                No              100
```

I believe that dplyr or some other simple function may be able to do this but I am not sure how to go about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking is how to extract the set of observational units that are present in all years of your data. Here is one method using base R for a data.frame named dataSet:

```
# get a table of the frequency counts of each ID
idCount <- table(dataSet$uniqueIDs)
# keep the IDs (converted back to integers) that have the most counts
keepIDs <- as.integer(names(idCount))[idCount == max(idCount)]
# save the new data set that includes those IDs
newDataSet <- dataSet[dataSet$uniqueIDs %in% keepIDs,]
```

Comment: There is a ")" missing in your second line of code @Imo. Nonetheless, this is an elaborate solution!

Comment: Thanks @Imo , this was really helpful. I think keepIDs <- as.integer(names(idCount)[idCount == max(idCount)](names(idCount) has a missing ")", but it worked after I added the ).

Comment: @Imo, for my large dataset, when I coerce the names is the second line of the code, I get an error message: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range, and the result of keepIDs is NA. Do you have any idea as to how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: How many unique IDs do you have? (use `length(unique(uniqueIDs))` to check). If the number of IDs exceeds ~2.19 billion, or any of the IDs is greater than ~2190000000 then this would be a result. If this is the case, you could try the `as.numeric()` function, which should work, though there is some risk of rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` the dataset by years and blend the resulting annual list entries back together using `merge` along with `all = FALSE` (default). Like that, you end up with those values of 'uniqueID' that exist during all years under investigation.

```
## sample data
dat <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2011, 4), rep(2012, 2), rep(2013, 3)), 
                  UniqueID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3), 
                  Bench.St = c("Yes", "No", "No", NA, "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), 
                  SiteEUI = c(450, 300, NA, 350, 400, 200, 500, 100, 475))

## split data by year and merge by 'uniqueID', discard non-matching entries
lst <- split(dat, dat$Year)

mrg <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "UniqueID"), lst)

## subset data based on remaining values of 'uniqueID'
dat[dat$UniqueID %in% mrg$UniqueID, ]

  Year UniqueID Bench.St SiteEUI
1 2011        1      Yes     450
2 2011        2       No     300
5 2012        1       No     400
6 2012        2      Yes     200
7 2013        1      Yes     500
8 2013        2       No     100
```

Comment: Thanks so much @fdetsch , that worked!! this is my first time posting and I did not realize I would get a response so quickly.

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer then @TobiAdekanye ;-) glad to help!

Comment: I realized that while the code worked for a small dataset, for a larger dataset of about 50,000 rows and 28 columns, the merge function shows a warning. I have about 4000 rows in yr 1, 15000 in yr2, 170000 in year 3 and 13,000 in year 4. I was expecting about 2000 rows but getting results of almost 14000 rows. Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: So what's the warning message? Or could you maybe provide the full dataset in your question, e.g. via Dropbox?

Comment: Here's the link:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z34gqjgx1u25y2z/AADP9pjuWhH4e5biOxuhM5Rta?dl=0 . I also put a snippet of the code and the xls files. Thanks! - Tobi

Comment: You needn't care about the warning message since it is only about duplicated column names in our temporary variable `mrg`. Regarding the resulting 14,000 rows, this needn't be an error. One value of `UniqueID` might occur only once in the 2012 dataset, but 2 (or even more times) in another. As you see from `length(unique(mrg$BBL))` when considering the Dropbox files, there are `3266` BBLs that occur during all years.

Comment: Thanks so much @fdetsch

Comment: so sorry for asking so many questions, I would like to know how to go about extracting just the 3266 BBLs for each year. I tried to include a unique but it is not working @fdetsch